# Code and time complexity of multiplication à la française

Tags: recursion, multiplication

This references the multiplication algorithm in Chapter 1 of *Algorithms* by Dasgupta et al.

I am trying to understand how the code for multiplication à la française works from the multiplication by hand. This is the example given.

[image: by hand]

This is the code given for it.

[image: code]

I went ahead and did multiplication of $13 \times 11$ (odd) case and $13 \times 10$ (even) in a spreadsheet and this is what I got.

[image: spreadsheet example]

It seems to me that in the code the rows of the columns are flipped with respect to handwritten example, that is, in $13 \times 11$, the 1 shows up where 13 is and not where 104 is as in the handwritten example. I still get the correct answer. Where did I make a mistake? In the evaluation or understanding the conversion from handwritten algorithm to algorithm in code.

I also have trouble seeing how to get $O(n^2)$ for the time complexity. I understand that there is bit shifting and addition and so at some point, assuming both $x$ and $y$ are n bits, we end up adding $1 + 2 + 3 + \dots + n = \frac{n}{2}(n+1) = O(n^2)$ but aren't we shifting the bits $n$ times and therefore need to multiply by another factor of $n$ to get $O(n^3)$?

This is what I get when I think of the equation for master theorem: $T(n) = T(\frac{n}{2}) + O(n)$ because there is 1 recursive call and the problem is halved and it takes $O(n)$ time to add n bits. However, this equation would give me $\Theta(n)$ which is wrong.  What step did I miss in the recurrence equation?

Answer (score 1):

In the function $T(n)$, the parameter $n$ represents the length of the input in bits. The recursive call reduces $y$ to $\lfloor y/2 \rfloor$, which reduces the length of the input by a single bit. Hence the recurrence is really $T(n) = T(n-1) + O(n)$, whose solution is indeed $T(n) = O(n^2)$.

Comment: Is the order of the operations flipped though between the handwritten approach and the recursive one in the pseudcode? I am not saying that it doesn't work. Just different order.

Comment: I’m not familiar with this algorithm, so cannot answer.